# How can I take a high-resolution screenshot?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, screenshots, screen-resolution

I'm using a Nexus 5 running on Lollipop 5.1, and I can take a screenshot by holding <kbd>POWER</kbd> and <kbd>VOLUME-DOWN</kbd>. However, screenshots appear to be limited by the resolution of the device's screen. Specifically, it's `1080x1920` for the Nexus 5.

[image: sample-screenshot]

Is there a way (through the use of developer tools, a specialised app, or otherwise) to take a screenshot of higher resolution?

Comment: if the screen only prints out 1080x1920 pixels then where do you get the extended pixels?

Comment: By simulating a larger screen size and taking a screenshot of that

Answer (score 2):

Even with development tools, screenshots are only of the pixel size of the device. You could try running the app in a emulator with higher resolution but all of those pixels may cause the emulator to lag. Or get a device like a Nexus 10 which runs at the higher resolutions.